Problem loading an amzi! prolog xpl file from a vba program
I have a program that used an xpl compiled from an old version fo Amzi! prolog. Any use of that prolog or of the xpl says that the activation had been made too long ago and that I should reactivate that prolog. That prolog is installed on a PC whose network card doesn't work, so I cannot reactivate that prolog because of that. A technician intalled other partitions of win10 to which i cannot move the old prolog.
So I download the latest version of Amzi prolog to another pc with win11. I rebuilt the xpl file with the new prolog. when I run my  program, the call to load the amzi.dll works (at last!), but when the program tries to load the xpl file i get a -1 error code. The absolute path of the xpl file mentioned in the program is identical to the one of the xpl file. Any solution? I must settle that rapidly
my trials have been described above

"That prolog is installed on a PC whose network card doesn't work, so I cannot reactivate that prolog because of that." - this would be the easiest thing to workaround; USB network adapters are common and relatively cheap, both wired and WiFi.
